# #import <ShinobiCharts/ShinobiChart.h> is missing

Tags: ios, objective-c, shinobi

I followed this github project to create a line graph.Here that project [Here](https://github.com/shinobicontrols/charts-accelerometer-visualisation). while I download and run i **get error : `ShinobiCharts/ShinobiChart.h` file  not found.** i also searched the framework in xcode. But its not in xcode framework. please help me to solve this.

What i need to do to add that `ShinobiCharts/ShinobiChart.h` header file to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install the ShinobiCharts libraries, you can get them from here: [ShinobiCharts](https://www.shinobicontrols.com/shinobicharts).

Comment: yes, i used free trial and it download the framework. after adding that frame work  got 75 errors. not able to run .

Comment: i am following this link project https://www.shinobicontrols.com/ios/shinobicharts/code-samples/view-project?repo=charts-accelerometer-visualisation

Comment: after trail folder downloaded . i saw shinobichart.framework . then i drag and drop to my project.

Comment: i too added all frameworks including security.framework